# iOS not saving all images

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, uiimage

In my app I have a button. If you tap it you can download a couple of images (13) to your photo library.
I created an array that holds the images, named "1", "2", "3", "4", etc. like this: (I checked, the array holds all 13 images)

```
var myPhotos: NSMutableArray = []
for i in 1...13 {
    let img = UIImage(named: "\(i)")!
    myPhotos.addObject(img)
}
```

I then save all the images to the photo library:

```
var photo = UIImage()
var j = 0
for photo in myPhotos {
    j++
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo as! UIImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
print(j)
print("done")
```

In the photo library of my simulator there are all the 13 images. When running this on my iPad that number varies a lot, from like 8 to 12 but never 13. That's why I put `j` there. It proves that the loop runs all the way through the array (j is 13 in the console) and "done" is also being printed.

What is the problem here?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how are the images named in your app?

Comment: You again :D - as stated above: "1", "2", "3", etc.

Comment: first of all you can simplify your loop: `for i in 1...13 {
      let img = UIImage(named: "\(i)")!
      myPhotos.addObject(img)
    }` - so you do not need that `var i = 0` before and the `i++` afterwards...

Comment: True that, changed, thanks.

Comment: Soo...any idea about this, @AndréSlotta?

Comment: Cool, thanks so far!

Comment: Have you checked that there are actually 13 image? In the loop print see information about each image such as the description or size.

Comment: Yes, checked that. There are 13 images. Otherwise the simulator would not be able to save 13 images in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var myPhotos = [UIImage]()
  var savedPhotos = 0

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // setup photos
    for i in 1...13 {
      let img = UIImage(named: "\(i).jpg")! // remove the ".jpg" for you to work
      myPhotos.append(img)
    }

    // save photos
    saveNextPhotoToPhotosAlbum()
  }

  func saveNextPhotoToPhotosAlbum() {
    if let photo = myPhotos.first {
      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
    }
  }

  func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    if error == nil {
      print("saved \(++savedPhotos). photo")
      myPhotos.removeFirst()
      saveNextPhotoToPhotosAlbum()
    }
  }

}
```

in my case i used .jpg images so maybe you have to remove the extension in the for loop to make it work for you!

Comment: Works great! Thank you! Any comment on why mine did not work?

Comment: sure. the problem is that in your case a new saving action sometimes starts before the last saving action completed because the method works asynchronously.. then the system gets confused and strange things happen. :) in my case i start with saving the next image when the completion handler tells me that the last saving action finished.